# Download entire website with videos using wget

Tags: linux, video, wget, vimeo

I have been using wget to download website but I have come across a bit of trouble if the website has videos from youtube, vimeo or others.

I can't seem to get rid of the ads as well.

The website that I am trying to get at the moment is :
https://www.ctrlpaint.com

I only need it temporarily be cause I have to work at a place where there is no internet. So I don't want to go to the hassle of downloading all the videos from vimeo.

Thanks for the help, let me know if you need more precision or if you want me to try anything.

I'm using gentoo.

The command I used was:

```
$ wget \ --recursive \ --no-clobber \ --page-requisites \ --html-extension \ --convert-links \ --restrict-file-names=windows \ --domains website.org \ --no-parent \ website_to download
```

It left me with the full website but looks to connect to the internet for the videos.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the videos are on a different host, I think.

This *would* work

```
wget -H -r --level=1 -k -p --no-clobber https://www.ctrlpaint.com/
```

The -H option includes other hosts. That being said, the video host here is vimeo, and when I tried it they detected the wget user agent and refused to actually send the video.

As an aside, this kind of thing is generally considered bad form, as the host you are mirroring has to pay for bandwidth. (And in fact may refuse to fulfill some requests, sending a too many requests error response.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the videos are not downloading is because they are not a single file, they are a stream of multiple files or chunks.

Websites like Vimeo or YouTube will be most likely using DASH or HLS, which is all HTTP Video Streaming. This  requires that you open the video with one of their players. After you make the initial request for the video to the server, the server sends back a manifest file with a list of all the links for the movie chunks. From there the player will send the subsequent requests for each of the movie chunks.

The server denies you access to the manifest or chunks when using wget or curl because there are some requirements and auth necessary for you to be able to get access to the files. The player takes care of all that, that's why you have to use one of their players.

You are probably in need of an app that can download the YouTube videos. I'm pretty sure you can find some options out there.

Good luck!